# 取得したキーを使ってWebAPIにリクエストを送信する方法が知りたい。

Tags: c#

提示コードですがwebサイトの開発ぺージから登録したクライアントキー、クライアントシークレット、アクセストークンを使って
APIにリクエストを送信したいのですが提示コードのコメント部のように行ってもどれも403エラーが返ってきてしまいます。

※マストドンAPIです

###### 知りたいこと

webページで登録したアプリケーションを使ってＡＰＩにリクエストを送信する方法が知りたい

###### 試したこと

参考サイトのリファレンスを見て行って試しに登録したキーを入力して色々試しましたがどれもエラーが返ってきます。
`https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/timelines/public`リクエストパラメータが必要ないものも試しましたが同じエラーが出ます。

###### 確認したこと

認証につきましてはwebページにて完了済みでそこそこ時間も経っているので
時間経過というエラーが原因ということはないと思います、

###### 参考サイト

リファレンス: https://docs.joinmastodon.org/methods/accounts/
試したリクエスト：　https://docs.joinmastodon.org/methods/accounts/#following

###### 提示コード

```cs
        static void Print()
        {
 //String url = "https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/accounts?Authorization=-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&username=shigurechan&password=Shigurechan7240&agreement=true&locale=ja";
            //String url = "https://mstdn.jp/oauth/authorize?response_type=read&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
            //String url = "https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/apps?client_name=test&redirect_uris=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
            //String url = "https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/apps?client_name=test&redirect_uris=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
            //String url = "https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/accounts/verify_credentials?Authorization=EedvO1rwNiq8-KJsRnRowCfak7KXc9ggmdQh84EI33k";
            String url = "https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/timelines/public";

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            Stream response_stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response_stream);
            var obj_from_json = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadToEnd());

            Console.WriteLine(obj_from_json);

   
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Print();


            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Comment: [`/api/v1/apps`](https://docs.joinmastodon.org/methods/apps/#create-an-application) はクライアントアプリケーションＡの権限を用いて、別のクライアントアプリケーションＢを作成するAPIです。呼び出すAPIは意図したものなのでしょうか？ 過去の質問でのやり取りから、質問することそれ自身が目的になってしまっていて、ご自身の達成したいことを見失っているように見受けられます。

Comment: なるほど。きずきませんでした。自分のやりたいことは認証してそのアカウントがフォローしているユーザーのタイムライン等を表示させたいのですが

Comment: @sayuri  > ライアントアプリケーションＡの権限を用いて、別のクライアントアプリケーションＢを作成するAPIです 普通の感覚だとそうなのですが、このAPIは異なります。 *OAuth: Public* とあるように、このエンドポイントの使用に認証は不要です。（任意のアプリケーションが数多のサーバーに対応する必要がある以上、そういうclient作成方法になっています。）

Comment: @hinaloe ありがとうございます。ご指摘の通りで私のコメントは誤っていました。/api/v1/apps には認証が要らなさそうですね。ただし、本来の目的は followingを取得することだそうで、こちらには認証が必要なことに変わりなく回答はそのまま適用できるかなと。あと、認証不要とはいえアプリ作成を乱発するとサーバーに負荷をかけるので回答としても避けるべきかなと思いました。質問者さん環境で動作しないのは不明ですが。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

認証を行うサンプルコードです。

C#は`Main`メソッドの中身を直接書いても認識しますし、`Main`メソッドは`async`化可能なため、`await`をそのまま利用できます。[`WebRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.net.webrequest?view=net-7.0)は非推奨化されて久しいため、後継の[`HttpClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-7.0)を使用しています。

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Net.Http.Headers;
using System.Net.Http.Json;
using System.Text.Json;

var client_id = "";         // アプリのクライアントキー
var client_secret = "";     // アプリのクライアントシークレット

using var client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://mstdn.jp") };
// MastodonはUser-Agentが必須なようで、設定されていないと 403 になる。
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("test/1.0");

{
    // ブラウザーを起動し、利用者にアプリケーションの承認を求める。得られたコードを受け取る。
    Process.Start("explorer.exe", $"\"{client.BaseAddress}/oauth/authorize?client_id={client_id}&scope=read&redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob&response_type=code\"");
    Console.Write("Input code: ");
    var code = Console.ReadLine();
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
        throw new Exception();

    // 得られたコードを使ってアクセストークンを取得する。
    var parameter = new Dictionary<string, string> {
        { "client_id", client_id },
        { "client_secret", client_secret },
        { "redirect_uri", "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob" },
        { "grant_type", "authorization_code" },
        { "code", code },
        { "scope", "read" },
    };
    using var response = await client.PostAsync("https://mstdn.jp/oauth/token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(parameter));
    var token = await response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode().Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<Token>();

    // アクセストークンをclientに記憶させる。このclientを使って他のサイトにアクセスするとこのトークンが流出してしまうので注意。
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "token.access_token");
}

{
    // 承認した利用者のアカウント情報を取得する。
    var account = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<Account>("/api/v1/accounts/verify_credentials");

    // アカウントIDを用いることで承認した利用者のfollowingを取得する。
    var followings = await client.GetStringAsync($"/api/v1/accounts/{account.id}/following");
    Console.WriteLine(followings);
}

// JSONのデシリアライズ用レコード
public record Token(string access_token);
public record Account(string id);
```

Comment: 詳細にありがとうございます。質問ですが以下の行で例外が発生するのですがこれは何が原因なのでしょうか？行`var followings = await client.GetStringAsync($"https://mstdn.jp/api/v1/accounts/{account.id}/following");`　エラー [ System.AggregateException: 'One or more errors occurred. (Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).)'
 ]

Comment: またAccountを見ると`Account { id =  }`と表示されます

Comment: @samidare_chan  `token`は取得できていますか？

Comment: Console.WriteLine(token.access_token);をしてみましたが何も表示されません。なぜでしょか？自分もいろいろいじってみましたが原因がわかりません。また最後のacocuntも何も表示されていないです

Comment: @samidare_chan  得られたコードは入力しましたか？

Comment: はい、コピペしました、またclinet_id,client_secretもコピペして入力しました。こちらの環境でしょうか？

Comment: 解決しました。web上で作成したキーの権限にフォローというところにチェックが入っていなかったためでした。